# Set selecInput to have no option selected

Tags: r, shiny

When running the app, you will see that `Option 1` is already selected, however it is strange because in `ui` I inserted `selected="No option selected"`. So what am I doing wrong?

My idea is that when running the algorithm, there is no option selected in `selectInput`.

Executable code below:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fluidRow(
        column(
          width = 6,
          selectInput("test", label = h5("Choose"),choices = list("Option1 " = "1", "Option2" = "2", selected="No option selected")),
      ))),
    mainPanel(

    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to put an empty string in `choices`:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fluidRow(
        column(
          width = 6,
          selectInput("test", 
                      label = h5("Choose"),
                      choices = list("", "Option1 " = "1", "Option2" = "2"), 
                      selected=NULL),
        ))),
    mainPanel(
      
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]